# getting a unique values from array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I currently have an array that looks like the one below but I only want to display show results in the array from which are unique (description), I presume with array_unique? but I keep getting the same results?

Here is my array:

```
$taglist = array(5) { 
[0]=> array(5) { 
    ["id"]=> string(2) "27" 
    ["page_id"]=> string(2) "18" 
    ["description"]=> string(10) "Web Design" 
    ["slug"]=> string(10) "web-design" 
    ["visibility"]=> string(7) "visible"
} 
[1]=> array(5) { 
    ["id"]=> string(2) "29" 
    ["page_id"]=> string(2) "18" 
    ["description"]=> string(3) "Tutorials" 
    ["slug"]=> string(3) "tutorials" 
    ["visibility"]=> string(7) "visible"
}
[2]=> array(5) {
    ["id"]=> string(2) "31"
    ["page_id"]=> string(2) "21"
    ["description"]=> string(3) "tag" 
    ["slug"]=> string(3) "tag"
    ["visibility"]=> string(7) "visible"
}
[3]=> array(5) { 
    ["id"]=> string(2) "32" 
    ["page_id"]=> string(2) "21" 
    ["description"]=> string(10) "Web Design" 
    ["slug"]=> string(10) "web-design" 
    ["visibility"]=> string(7) "visible"
}
}
```

Here is my while:

```
$items      = array();
$results    = $taglist;

foreach ($results as $result)
{
$items[]= $result['description'];
$items  = array_unique($items);
}

echo '<ul>';
while ($tag_item = current($items))
{
echo '<li><a href="/'.$page['slug'].'/tag/'.$tag_item['slug'].'/">'.$tag_item['description'].'</a></li>';
    next($items);
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Dispalying the result of $a = var_export($taglist, 1); echo $a; and posting that instead of the dump would get more people copy/pasting your array and replying to your answer.  As it is we have to write it out again.

Comment: if I do echo $item I just get the Array come back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$taglist = array(
0 => array('description'=>'one'),
1 => array('description'=>'two'),
2 => array('description'=>'one'),
3 => array('description'=>'three'),
4 => array('description'=>'one'),
);

// echo var_export($taglist, 1);  // uncomment to see the diff vs var_dump()

foreach($taglist as $tag){
$new[] = $tag['description'];

}

var_dump(array_unique($new));
```

Comment: Thanks looks like its pulling it through but I am only getting the first letter of each result??

Comment: any ideas on why I am only getting the  first letter?

$new = array_unique($new);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($new as $tag_item)
    {
     echo '<li><a href="/'.$page['slug'].'/tag/'.$tag_item['slug'].'/">'.$tag_item['description'].'</a></li>';
    }

Comment: `$new` is an 1-d array of strings, not a 2-d array, so `$tag_item['slug']` and `$tag_item['description']` shouldn't work.

Comment: @neoszion If you would show us the output of var_export() of your original array, then you would get yourself some definitive answers.  As it is, in order to test out my idea, I have to type out a test array.